# Stop Skeleton Flickering in Kinect for Windows

Tags: windows, position, kinect

Currently working on a project to find the X,Y position of the using who is standing in front of the kinect. 
Even though the user is standing still the X,Y keep changing because the kinect skeleton is flickering. Could someone help me how to figure out a way to stop the skeleton flickering

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the smoothing parameter? The following settings result in very smooth movements, but with a lot of latency.

```
TransformSmoothParameters smoothingParam = new TransformSmoothParameters
{
   Smoothing = 0.7f;
   Correction = 0.3f;
   Prediction = 1.0f;
   JitterRadius = 1.0f;
   MaxDeviationRadius = 1.0f;
};
sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(smoothingParam);
```

If that is not working good enough for you, I had developed a helper class for one of my kinect projects to smooth the coordinates of joints. You have to create an instance of the following helper class for each smoothed joint and call `GetSmoothedXPosition`/`GetSmoothedYPosition` with the screen coordinates of the joint:

```
internal class JointSmoothing
{
    #region Constants and Enumerations
    private const int QueueLength = 7;
    private const double BaseValue = 0.9;
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private readonly Queue<double> myXValues = new Queue<double>(QueueLength);
    private readonly Queue<double> myYValues = new Queue<double>(QueueLength);
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public double GetSmoothedXPosition(double x)
    {
        if (myXValues.Count >= QueueLength)
        {
            myXValues.Dequeue();
        }
        myXValues.Enqueue(x);

        return ExponentialMovingAverage(myXValues);
    }

    public double GetSmoothedYPosition(double y)
    {
        if (myYValues.Count >= QueueLength)
        {
            myYValues.Dequeue();
        }
        myYValues.Enqueue(y);

        return ExponentialMovingAverage(myYValues);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        myXValues.Clear();
        myYValues.Clear();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Implementation
    private static double ExponentialMovingAverage(Queue<double> values)
    {
        double numerator = 0;
        double denominator = 0;

        int valueCount = values.Count;
        int weight = valueCount - 1;
        foreach (double value in values)
        {
            numerator += value * Math.Pow(BaseValue, weight);
            denominator += Math.Pow(BaseValue, weight);
            weight--;
        }

        double average = values.Sum(); 
        average /= values.Count;
        numerator += average * Math.Pow(BaseValue, valueCount);
        denominator += Math.Pow(BaseValue, valueCount);

        return numerator / denominator;
    }
    #endregion
}
```